# SSH with login shell - Jenkins slave node

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, ssh

What is the best way to ssh with login shell, i.e. pass **-, -l, --login** not just for one off command.

Specifically this is for Jenkins Node, tried to add --login but it's probably something else. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see `Start Agent` used in "[How to Connect to Remote SSH Agents?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/222978868-How-to-Connect-to-Remote-SSH-Agents-) "

> Place the following in the Suffix Start Agent Command
>
> ```
> -jar-cache <path to jar cache directory>
> ```
>
> Make sure there’s a leading space so the parameters aren’t tacked directly onto the `slave.jar` itself.

So the prefix/suffix are for Java options, not SSH option.
That is because the [SSH Agent plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/) is likely using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), not system ssh.
So adding the option you want might not be directly possible.
Check though is the `.profile`/`.bashrc` are executed on the agent connection (as suggested by [this troubleshooting step](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/222978868-How-to-Connect-to-Remote-SSH-Agents-#iseetheerrorhudsonabortexceptionheaderjunkdetected)): that would be enough for you to set environment variable there.